# How to trigger socket event on Mongoose save in Node?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

This is my model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var timestamps = require('mongoose-timestamp');

var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

CategorySchema.plugin(timestamps);
CategorySchema.post('save', function () {
    console.log(this.name);
  });
var Category = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);

module.exports = Category;
```

Here is my index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const { mongoose } = require('./config/db.js');
var routes = require('./routes/routes');
var j = require('./utility/mailer');
var app = express();

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));

app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:4200' }));
app.use(express.static('uploads'));
//app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setTimeout(10000, function () {
        console.log('timeout call');
        res.status(408).send({ 'res': 'timed out' });
        //res.end(408);
        return;
    });
    next();
});
app.use('/', routes);

app.set("port", (process.env.PORT || 3000));
/*
app.listen(app.get("port"), function () {
 console.log("Server started: http://localhost:" + app.get("port") + "/");
}) */
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});


var io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {
    handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
        const headers = {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin,
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
        };
        res.writeHead(200, headers);
        res.end();
    }
});

let timerId = null,
    sockets = new Set();
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connected');
    sockets.add(socket);
    console.log(`Socket ${socket.id} added`);

    if (!timerId) {
        startTimer();
    }

       socket.emit('new data', { data: 'new data'});
    socket.on('clientdata', data => {
    });



    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    });

});
function startTimer() {
    timerId = setInterval(() => {
        if (!sockets.size) {
            clearInterval(timerId);
            timerId = null;;
        }
        for (const s of sockets) {
            s.emit('data', { data: 'some data' });
        }

    }, 2000);
}
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sonarqubeScanner = require('sonarqube-scanner');

gulp.task('default', function (callback) {
    sonarqubeScanner({
        serverUrl: "https://localhost:8081",
    }, callback);
});
io.listen(8000);
```

I want to trigger an event for the socket inside the mongoose save-hook in the category model file. Can you suggest a way to do it? The hook is working. But I cannot figure out a way to possibly trigger an event from the socket.on since it is in the index.js.

It is fine if you do not keep the timer there. That was just for emitting the events within an interval, as I was following a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the IO a global variable so you can access it anywhere on the app.

```
global.io = require("socket.io").listen(server, {
handlePreflightRequest: (req, res) => {
    const headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": req.headers.origin,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end();
}});
```

Then in your save hook

```
io.emit("event-name",payload);
```